# Copy phonenumber with python

Tags: javascript, python, css, xpath

Im struggling with python3. I teached myself the basics. Now im learning webdriver and bs4. FUN!

I want to scrape the phonenumber of a page. In other cases i made a working script. But now im on a page that gives me a headache!

I think the problem is that the content is dynamicly loaded. (Its not on the pagesource)

This is the page: https://www.dnls.nl/locatie/diergaarde-blijdorp-rotterdam

There is a element with this text: Toon telefoonnummer. I can click it with:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Toon telefoonnummer").click().
```

The phonenumber is visible but for my eyes only! Im trying to grab the number for hours now with xpath and css but i can't grab it!

In the pagesource i see this:

```
<div class="show_onclick">
    <div class="text-center telephone-field"><a class="set-align" :href="'tel:'+project.contact_phone">{{project.contact_phone}}</a></div>
    <div class="text-center">{{project.contact_textline}}</div>
</div>
```

This is my last code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

try:
        #telefoonnummer
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Toon telefoonnummer").click() #This works
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        telefoonnummer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='main-inner']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]/div/div[1]/a").text
        print(telefoonnummer)

except:
        print("")
```

Is there a way to scrape this kind of content?

UPDATE: i found the data in a javascript thats in the head of the pagesource. Its a massive javascript and it contains:

```
"contact_name":"Blijdorp Happenings","contact_phone":"010 4431415","contact_email":"sales@diergaardeblijdorp.nl"
```

What is my goal: I want to find the phonenumber, copy to phonenumber and safe it in a var 'telefoonnummer'

Kind Regards!

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me at least, what you want, do you want the phone number you have entered into that box during your session?

Comment: If you can click the button and get the phone number to show, then you should be able to grab the element <div class="text-center telephone-field"> which contains a <a> tag with your phone number.
Tip: Use right click + inspect element to see dynamic content.

Comment: What is my goal: I want to find the phonenumber, copy to phonenumber and safe it in a var 'telefoonnummer'. I use the inspector and other tools to detect xpaths. If i use inspect element the number is visible. But python can't see it i believe! This is how the data is included: https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_display.asp